# Read a binary file to a linked list, (only reading the last node)

Tags: c, binary, linked-list

First, sorry I know this question gets asked a lot I have even read a couple of anwsers but still havent managed to write a working code. This is my basic loop but it only reads the last node, so what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

This is global:

```
struct Inventory
{
int cod;
int quant;
float price;
char name[30];
struct Inventory *next;
};
struct Inventory *inventory = NULL;
```

This is the function to read.

```
void load(void)
{
FILE *ptr;
ptr=fopen("inventory.dat", "rb+");
if (!ptr)
{
    return;

}
struct Inventory *p;
while(!feof(ptr))
{
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));
    fread(p, sizeof(struct Inventory), 1, ptr);
    p->next = inventory;
    inventory = p;
}

fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You will need another variable to store the most recent (`current`) pointer. The code is merely an example to show how the pointers connect.

`head` points to the beginning of the list, `current` points to the most recent addition to the list. The `->prox` pointer points to the next item in the list.

```
while(!feof(ptr))
{
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));
    if (!head)
    {
        head = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));   
        current = head;
    }
    fread(p, sizeof(struct Inventory), 1, ptr);
    current->prox = p;
    current = p;
}
```

Comment: thanks for you explanation. But im afraid i still dont get it.

Comment: The way I've found best when writing linked list code is to draw diagrams. That's helped my understanding. I draw a diagram with one (the header) node (and the pointers pointing to it), then another diagram for two nodes - with the pointer changes shown on the diagram.